# Check if virtual environment is activated and act accordingly in a Makefile

Tags: python, makefile, conda

I am using Python together with Anaconda and I want to have a rule `test` in my `Makefile`. However, I want to assert that when running `make test`, the right environment will be activated. When a `conda` environment is activated it defines the environment variable `$(CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV)`.

First I did:

```
REPO_NAME = my_repo

define execute_in_env
  source activate $(REPO_NAME); \
  $1
endef

test:
    $(call execute_in_env, pytest -v --ignore=src/foo)
```

This way, when I executed `make test` it activated the virtual environment and ran the test inside. Problem is that it is length. I want to check if `make` is executed from an activated virtual environment. To that end, I modified the code:

```
.PHONY: test
REPO_NAME = my_repo
define execute_in_env =
    $@echo "Checking if in environment"
    ifeq ($(CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV),$(REPO_NAME))
        $1
    else
        source activate $(REPO_NAME); \
        $1
    endif
endef
test:
    $(call execute_in_env, pytest -v --ignore=src/rebuydsutils)
```

With this implementation, the testing doesn't happen. I get a

```
make: Nothing to be done for `test'.
```

Answer (score 2):

The root problem is with the `=` in `define execute_in_env =`.   (you're also using an `ifeq` inside of a `define`, which is a bit of a sharp stick, but I don't think it will hurt you in this particular case).  Note that you're using functions where you don't need to -- functions are not very readable, and make the makefiles harder to maintain.   A simpler and cleaner way of doing the same thing would be:

```
ifeq ($(CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV),$(REPO_NAME))
    ACTIVATE_ENV := source activate $(REPO_NAME);
else
    ACTIVATE_ENV := true
endif

test: 
    $(ACTIVATE_ENV) && pytest -v --ignore=src/rebuydsutils;
```

Comment: To be clear, the syntax allowing the `=` sign with `define` was added in GNU make 3.82 (released July 2010).  If your version of GNU make is older than that, then you can't use this syntax.

Comment: I need a function as I want to call different executables from the virtual environment from different rules. I will add my modification as an answer. Feel free to update yours so I could accept it :)

Comment: Note that you can just as easily add `$(ACTIVATE_ENV) &&` in front of any of the recipes instead of using the `$(call ...)`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @John's answer, I wrote the following:

```
ifeq ($(CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV),$(REPO_NAME))
    ACTIVATE_ENV := true
else
    ACTIVATE_ENV := source activate $(REPO_NAME)
endif

# Execute python related functionalities from within the project's environment
define execute_in_env
    $(ACTIVATE_ENV) && $1
endef
```

Then, inside a rule I can have something like:

```
test:
    $(call execute_in_env, pytest -v --ignore=src/somepackage)
```